# Binding SpinEdit Value to the parent element from the DataTemplate in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress-wpf, devexpress-gridcontrol

I'm using `WPF` and dotnet 7 with `Devexpress` Controls (22), what I'm trying to achieve is to show some data inside my `GridControl` (TableView):

```cs
public class First
{
   
    public required string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Second> Seconds { get; set; }
}

public class Second
{
    public int Plus { get; set; }
}
```

my XAML is as follows:

```xml
<dxg:GridControl Name="MainGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew">
    <dxg:GridControl.View>
        <dxg:TableView Name="FirstTable" NewItemRowPosition="Bottom"  ShowGroupPanel="False" SearchPanelAllowFilter="True" SearchPanelHighlightResults="True"/>
    </dxg:GridControl.View>
    <dxg:GridControl.DetailDescriptor>
        <dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor Margin="10" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=models:First}" ItemsSourceBinding="{Binding Seconds}">
            <dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor.DataControl>
                <dxg:GridControl x:Name="SecondGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew">
                    <dxg:GridControl.View>
                        <dxg:TableView x:Name="SecondTable" NewItemRowPosition="Bottom" ShowGroupPanel="False" SearchPanelAllowFilter="True" SearchPanelHighlightResults="True">
                            <dxg:TableView.FormatConditions>
                                <dxg:FormatCondition Expression="true">
                                    <dx:Format Foreground="SlateGray"/>
                                </dxg:FormatCondition>
                            </dxg:TableView.FormatConditions>
                        </dxg:TableView>
                    </dxg:GridControl.View>
                    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Plus" Binding="{Binding Plus}" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance models:Second}">
                        <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <dxe:SpinEdit HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
                                               Mask="##0"  
                                               AllowSpinOnMouseWheel="True"
                                               EditValueType="{x:Type system:Int32}"
                                               EditValue="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type dxg:GridColumn}},Path=DataContext.Plus}"
                                               Increment="1"
                                               MinValue="0"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </dxg:GridColumn>
                </dxg:GridControl>
            </dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor.DataControl>
        </dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor>
    </dxg:GridControl.DetailDescriptor>
</dxg:GridControl>
```

as you can see its a nested Grid, which works fine, kinda..

the problem is that I CANNOT bind the **plus** value to the SpinEdit, I tried different ways but so far nothing worked,
the value is actually inside the `<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Plus" ..`, so if I completely remove the `DataTemplate` it shows the value successfully, but it fails to bind it to the SpinEdit.

the `FindAncestor` should fetch the parent data but it fails with

```
Cannot find source: RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.GridColumn', AncestorLevel='1'.
```

also by using `TemplatedParent` instead of FindAncestor, I got this exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Reflection.MethodBase' instances are not supported. Path: $.TargetSite.'
```

what is my mistake here?

**UPDATE:**

I did this:

```xml
 <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Plus" x:Name="PlusColumn" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance models:Second}">
     <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <dxe:SpinEdit HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
                            Mask="##0"  
                            AllowSpinOnMouseWheel="True"
                            EditValue="{Binding ElementName=PlusColumn,Path=DataContext.Plus}"
                            Increment="1"
                            MinValue="0"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
 </dxg:GridColumn>
```

and I got no binding failure and no error, BUT it still doesn't show the value,
I even replaced the SpinEdit just to make sure its not the Control Problem, still nothing is shown.

Comment: I don't know about devexpress gridcontrol but in regular wpf gridview and datagrid, a column is an abstract thing. There's just a bunch of rows in a panel with cells in each row. I can't imagine how you'd get a cell in two things in wpf. Any given ui element can only have the one parent.

Comment: @Andy "2 things"? no its just a single element in that Cell and that is the SpinEdit thing, wdym 2 things?

Comment: Row is one parent. Column would be second.

Comment: You can see the visual tree easily in snoop. Less easily (imo) in the built in tooling.

Comment: so i cant get the data through parenting? what i "can" do ?